# Appropriate replacement function for toString method

Tags: java

I have below lines of code in my java source. I'm not supposed to use "toString" method. Can you pls suggest any appropriate method for it.

```
public  void logDebug(String eventType,  String info)   {
        String[] source =   getSourceAndLineNumber();
        StringBuffer log=   new StringBuffer(eventType).append(":::").append(source[0]);
        log.append(":::").append(source[1]).append(":::\n").append(info).append("\n");
        logInfo.log(Level.INFO, log.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you? (I'd also recommend a `StringBuilder`, but that comes down to needs)

Comment: You could use `StringBuffer#getChars` to copy the contents to another `char` array, but you'd probably need to use `new String(charArray)` to create something useful from it, which seems like a lot of work just to avoid `toString`. You could use `StringBuffer#subSequence` which returns a `CharSequence`, but it's all just amounting to the same thing...

Comment: `String.valueOf()` .. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logInfo.log(Level.INFO, log + "")`. Though that will implicitly call the `toString()` method.

Comment: That's a hack. [Look how string concatenation works](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/08/compiler-version-string-concatenation.html)

Comment: Not sure what your point is. The correct way would be to use the `toString()` method, but that wasn't allowed. This is a way of achieving the same result without explicitly calling the `toString()` method.

Comment: THe guidelines given to me is not to use toString() method. And the code suggested works. Thank You.